# AWS Amplify Deploy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deploy

У меня проблемы с деплоем на AWS Amplify. До этого использовал хероку и всё было ок. У меня приложение на фронте React на бэкенде express.

Для хероку работает такой алгоритм. Устанавливаю зависимости для сервера `npm install` , далее иду в папку client и устанавливаю зависимости для фронта `npm install`. Далее делаю билд фронта `npm run build`.

В корне приложения у меня есть procfile в котором прописано `web: npm start`. После деплоя на хероку, сервер стартует в продакшн моде и отдает мне сбилженый `index.html` из `client/build` папки. Всё круто.

Для деплоя на Amplify я использую такой `amplify.yml`

```
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    PROD: true
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm install
    build:
      commands: []
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - cd client
        - npm install
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: client/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Билд и деплой проходят хорошо, я могу зайти по ссылке и посмотреть на свое приложение. Но в нём отсутвует серверная часть. Хотелось бы решить эту проблему

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: Сделал. Если сталкивались с таким, могли бы что то подсказать?

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не могу, но надеюсь, что кто-то найдётся.